# Python, Tkinter - ttk.Progressbar in a separate thread

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I googled a lot on this but I still haven't found what I'm looking for.
This is a classic question, I guess, but I still can't figure it out.

I have this Python/Tkinter code. The code starts a pretty CPU-heavy process by trivially calling it with `os.system(cmd)`. I want a progress bar (oscillating one, not progressive) which shows users something is actually happening.
I guess I just have to kind of start the thread containing the progress bar before calling `os.system`, then call `os.system` while progress bar thread is running, close progress bar thread and destroy associate `Toplevel()`.

I mean, Python is pretty flexible, is it possible to do this without much pain?
I know killing a thread from another thread is unsafe (due to data sharing), but this two threads do not share any data as far as I know.

Would it be possible to go like this:

```
progressbar_thread.start()
os.system(...)
progressbar_thread.kill()
```

If that's not possible, I still don't understand how to pass 'signal' variables between the two threads.

Thank you,

Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the type of thing you are after?

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk, threading

class progress():
    def __init__(self, parent):
            toplevel = Toplevel(tk)
            self.progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(toplevel, orient = HORIZONTAL, mode = 'indeterminate')
            self.progressbar.pack()
            self.t = threading.Thread()
            self.t.__init__(target = self.progressbar.start, args = ())
            self.t.start()
            #if self.t.isAlive() == True:
             #       print 'worked'

    def end(self):
            if self.t.isAlive() == False:
                    self.progressbar.stop()
                    self.t.join()


def printmsg():
    print 'proof a new thread is running'


tk = Tk()
new = progress(tk)
but1 = ttk.Button(tk, text= 'stop', command= new.end)
but2 = ttk.Button(tk, text = 'test', command= printmsg)
but1.pack()
but2.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: `progressbar.start()` returns immediately therefore `Thread` is completely useless here (it ends as soon as it starts). `printmsg` doesn't prove that the thread is running. You should not  call `__init__` directly; the syntax is: `Thread(target=some_func, args=func_args)`.

Comment: Still usefull, note that  isAlive() has been deprectaed for python 3, use is_alive() instead

Answer (score 1):

You don't need threads in this case. Just use [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess#subprocess.Popen) to start the subprocess.

To notify the GUI when the process ends you could implement polling using `widget.after()` method:

```
process = Popen(['/path/to/command', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'etc'])
progressbar.start()

def poller():
    if process.poll() is None: # process is still running
       progressbar.after(delay, poller)  # continue polling
    else:
       progressbar.stop() # process ended; stop progress bar

delay = 100  # milliseconds
progressbar.after(delay, poller) # call poller() in `delay` milliseconds
```

If you want to stop the process manually without waiting:

```
if process.poll() is None: # process is still running
   process.terminate()
   # kill process in a couple of seconds if it is not terminated
   progressbar.after(2000, kill_process, process)

def kill_process(process):
    if process.poll() is None:
        process.kill()
        process.wait()
```

Here's a [complete example](https://gist.github.com/4067619).